# Passing struct through socket via recv C/C++

Tags: linux, sockets, struct, timeslots

Helo, i am trying to pass it like this

```
typedef struct t_timeSliceRequest{
unsigned int processId;
unsigned int timeRequired;
int priority;
}timeSliceRequest;

struct t_timeSliceRequest request = { 1,2,1 };
sendFlag = send(socketID,(timeSliceRequest *) &request, sin_size ,0);
```

and on server side

```
recvFlag = recv(socketID,(timeSliceRequest *) &request,sin_size,0);
```

but its receiving garbage, even recv returning -1, please help

This is my full Conde

```
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

enum priority_e{ high, normal, low };

typedef struct t_timeSliceRequest{
    unsigned int processId;
    unsigned int timeRequired;
    int priority;
}timeSliceRequest;

typedef struct t_TimeSliceResponse {
    timeSliceRequest original_req;

    // Unix time stamp of when process was started on server
    unsigned int time_started;

    // Waiting and running time till end of CPU bust
    unsigned int ttl;

} TimeSliceResponse;


int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int socketID = 0, clientID = 0;
    char sendBuffer[1024], recvBuffer[1024];
    time_t time;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr, clientAddr;
    struct t_timeSliceRequest request = {1,1,0};

memset(sendBuffer, '0', sizeof(sendBuffer));
memset(recvBuffer, '0', sizeof(recvBuffer));

fprintf(stdout,"\n\n --- Server starting up --- \n\n");
fflush(stdout);

socketID = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(socketID == -1){
    fprintf(stderr, " Can't create Socket");
    fflush(stdout);
}

servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servAddr.sin_port = htons(5000);
servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

int bindID, sin_size, recvFlag;
bindID = bind(socketID, (struct sockaddr *)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)); // Casting sockaddr_in on sockaddr and binding it with socket id
if(bindID!=-1){
    fprintf(stdout," Bind SucessFull");
    fflush(stdout);
    listen(socketID,5);
    fprintf(stdout, " Server Waiting for connections\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    while(1){
        sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        clientID = accept(socketID, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, &sin_size);
        fprintf(stdout,"\n I got a connection from (%s , %d)", inet_ntoa(clientAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(clientAddr.sin_port));
        fflush(stdout);
        sin_size = sizeof(request);
        recvFlag = recv(socketID, &request,sin_size,0);
        perror("\n Err: ");
        fprintf(stdout, "\n recvFlag: %d", recvFlag);
        fprintf(stdout, "\n Time Slice request received:\n\tPid: %d \n\tTime Required: %d ", ntohs(request.processId), ntohs(request.timeRequired));
        fflush(stdout);
        snprintf(sendBuffer, sizeof(sendBuffer), "%.24s\n", ctime(&time));
        write(clientID, sendBuffer, strlen(sendBuffer));
        close(clientID);
        sleep(1);
    }
}else{
    fprintf(stdout, " Unable to Bind");
}
close(socketID);
return 0;
}
```

And Client Code is:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

enum priority_e{ high = +1, normal = 0, low = -1};

typedef struct t_timeSliceRequest{
    unsigned int processId;
    unsigned int timeRequired;
    int priority;
}timeSliceRequest;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int socketID = 0 /*Socket Descriptor*/, n = 0;
    char recvBuffer[1024];
    memset(recvBuffer, '0',sizeof(recvBuffer));
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;

    struct t_timeSliceRequest request = { 1,2,high };

    if(argc!=2){
        fprintf(stderr,"\n Usage: %s <ip of server> \n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    socketID = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(socketID == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "\n Can't create socket \n");
        return 1;
    }

    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(5000);

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servAddr.sin_addr)==-1){
        fprintf(stderr, "\n Unable to convert given IP to Network Form \n inet_pton Error");
        return 1;
    }

    int connectFlag, sendFlag = 0;
    connectFlag = connect(socketID, (struct sockaddr *)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
    if(connectFlag == -1){
       fprintf(stderr, " Connection Failed\n");
       return 1;
    }

    int sin_size = sizeof(struct t_timeSliceRequest);
    fprintf(stdout, " \n %d \n %d \n %d", request.processId, request.timeRequired, request.priority);
    sendFlag = send(socketID, &request, sin_size ,0);
    fprintf(stdout, "\nSend Flag: %d\n", sendFlag);

    n = read(socketID, recvBuffer, sizeof(recvBuffer)-1);
    recvBuffer[n] = 0;
    fprintf(stdout, "%s",recvBuffer);
    if(n < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, " Read error\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the full Code, its giving 'Transport endpoint is not connected'

Comment: Could you check, what `errno` (or call `perror` and see its results) is after `recv` returning -1?

Comment: When i do it like this
'perror(recvFlag)'
it gives segmentation fault on server
and read Error on client, i've never used 'perror' before

Comment: Just use `perror("our error message: ")`, for example, or simply `perror(NULL)`, which won't prepend anything to the printed error message.

Comment: its giving
Transport endpoint is not connected.
BTW `sin_size = sizeof(request);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transport endpoint is not connected error is returned when your socket isn't bound to any (port,address) pair.

If it's a server side, you should use the socket descriptor that is returned by `accept` call. In case of a client - you should use a socket that is returned by the successful call to `connect`.

Btw, sending structure the way you are is quite dangerous. Compilers might insert padding bytes between structure members (invisible to you program, but they take space in the structure) to conform some alignment rules for the target platform. Besides, different platforms might have different endianness, which might screw your structure completely. If your client and server are compiled for different machines, the structure layout and endianness can be incompatible. To solve this problem, you can use **packed** structures. A way of declaring a structure as packed depends on a compiler. For GCC this can be done by means of adding a [special attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) to a structure.

Another way to solve this problem is to put each individual field of a structure to a raw byte-buffer manually. The receiving side should take all this data out in exactly the same way as the data was originally put into that buffer. This approach can be tricky, since you need to take into account a network byte order when saving multi-byte values (like int, long etc). There is a special set of functions like `htonl`, `htons`, `ntohs` etc for that.

**Updated**

In your server:

```
recvFlag = recv(socketID, &request,sin_size,0);
```

Here it should be

```
recvFlag = recv(clientID, &request,sin_size,0);
```

`socketID` is a passive socket and can only accept connections (not send any data).

What is more, the result of `accept` isn't checked for -1.

Comment: Added my Code to original post...  please take a look

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that sending structs like this over the network may lead to interoperability problems:

1. if source and destination have different endianess, you're going to receive wrong data (consider using functions like `htonl` to convert the data to network endianess)
2. you struct needs to be packed, otherwise different compilers can align differently the variables of the struct (see [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) to get an idea about aligning the variables)

In any case, `ENOTCONN` suggests an error establishing the connection between the two hosts.

Comment: I am using `ntohs()` fuction to translate, but the main problem i am facing is that `recv` is returning -1, but connection is established, it sends/receives other requests, but fails if i pack a struct with it.
Let me add my full code with my post, it will make it more clear